# How to get Similar record with percentage in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. I want to get similar record with percentage.

Please look my code:

users

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | fname      | lname    |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | sanjib     | pradhan  |
|  2 | aruna      | avipsa   |
|  3 | chinu      | sahu     |
|  4 | sradha     | behera   |
|  5 | debasish   | dash     |
|  6 | pikun      | behera   |
|  7 | pradep     | hardy    |
+----+------------+----------+
```

user_tags

```
+-----+---------+------------+
| id  | user_id | tag        |
+-----+---------+------------+
|  1  |  1      | php        |
|  2  |  1      | java       |
|  3  |  2      | java       |
|  4  |  1      | dotnet     |
|  5  |  2      | oracle     |
|  6  |  3      | oracle     |
|  7  |  3      | python     |
|  8  |  4      | sql        |
|  9  |  3      | java       |
+-----+---------+------------+
```

There have two table `users` and `user_tags` I need 3 records percentage. user_id 1 having 3 tags `php, java, dotnet` user_id 2 having 2 tags, user_id 3 having 3 tags and 4 having 1 tag.

Suppose my query based on id=2 in the users table. There have 2 tags on the tags table. I need these two tags with similar to other users tag.

> user_id=2
>
> tags=java,oracle

---

> user_id=1
>
> tags=php,java,dotnet (matches tag java is exist - percent should be number of matches tag/total tag) means 1/3

---

> user_id=3
>
> tags=oracle, python, java `2 tags matches(java and oracle)` percent should be 2/3

---

> user_id = 4, tag=sql (No matches tag so percent is 0%)

How to manage this by using MySQL and php code?

Comment: if you use **foreign key** problem solved easy and without big Query

Comment: Yes i am using **foreign ey**

Comment: if your table name `users` then  `user_tags` table column should come `users_id`. check once

Comment: I'm not sure that you know what a percentage is.

Comment: no @Abdulla column name `user_id` this is cakephp table model relation. i need mysql query then i will convert into cakephp format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the answer you want by left joining all the users with their tags, to user 2 with their tags.  Then we just count the appropriate values to get your percentage.

```
select u1.id, 
       count(ut2.tag) matches, 
       count(ut1.tag) total, 
       count(ut2.tag) / count(ut1.tag) pct
  from users u1
    inner join user_tags ut1
      on u1.id = ut1.user_id
    left join
      users u2
        inner join user_tags ut2
          on u2.id = ut2.user_id
    on ut2.tag = ut1.tag
      and u2.id = 2
  where u1.id <> 2
  group by u1.id
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6d6c/10)

How does this work? Before the group by and aggregate functions, the rows returned look like this:

```
id  fname   lname   id  user_id tag     id      fname   lname   id      user_id tag
1   sanjib  pradhan 2   1       java    2       aruna   avipsa  3       2       java
3   chinu   sahu    9   3       java    2       aruna   avipsa  3       2       java
3   chinu   sahu    6   3       oracle  2       aruna   avipsa  5       2       oracle
1   sanjib  pradhan 1   1       php     (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
1   sanjib  pradhan 4   1       dotnet  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
3   chinu   sahu    7   3       python  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
4   sradha  behera  8   4       sql     (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
```

As you can see - where the tag for the user on the left does not match the tag for the user on the right, null values are entered.  The `count` function in mysql ignores null values, and does not count them.  Because of this, when we group by u1.id (the id value at the far left) and count the number of tags they have (`ut1.tag`), we get the total of all of their tags. However, when we count the value for `ut2.tag`, we only get the total that aren't `null`, ie, only the ones that match.  This allows us to get your percentage.

**edit for comment**

You added the requirement in the comments to be able to compare against multiple users at once, since this means it may match the same tag more than once, we need to only count the distinct elements.

```
select u1.id, 
       count(distinct ut2.tag) matches, 
       count(ut1.tag) total, 
       count(distinct ut2.tag) / count(ut1.tag) pct
  from users u1
    inner join user_tags ut1
      on u1.id = ut1.user_id
    left join
      users u2
        inner join user_tags ut2
          on u2.id = ut2.user_id
    on ut2.tag = ut1.tag
      and u2.id IN (2,3)
  where u1.id NOT IN (2,3)
  group by u1.id
  having count(ut2.tag) > 0;
```

With your updated fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6d6c/54)

Comment: You are just calculate percent between `fname`. I think that is wrong. I am confused :(

Comment: @chatfun no i'm not. please try the demo.  `u1.fname` has a value for EVERY `u1.fname`. `u2.fname` only has a value when the tags match. `count` ignores nulls when it is counting.

There is no reason to count those particular fields, it could just as easily be `count(ut1.tag)` and `count(ut2.tag)`. In fact i'll change it to that because it groks a bit better

Comment: There was single id search but i need to search also 3 id along with 2. Please look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6d6c/13  i am getting 2 matches which id is 1 but actually there have one matches name `java` Please check and solve this query. Thanks.

Comment: That's changing the question quite a bit - you are getting two matches because both user 2 AND 3 have java

Comment: also those id is 2 and 3 and percentage grater than 0 or matches grater than 0 i need to show that record.

Comment: Yes i need two matches between 2 AND 3

Comment: oh, you want to delete the row with 0 matches? just add `having count(ut2.tag) > 0` after the `group by` line. i've updated the last query to show that